# Texshop not compiling \ref and \citet

Tags: texshop

A coauthor and I share a file.  When I compile it, there are no errors. However, when my coauthor compiles it, all \ref and \citet compile as [?]. He recently installed MacTex (and just reinstalled it to ensure that is not the issue).  He uses Texshop to compile (I do not). When he does, he gets lots of errors of the form:

> Package natbib Warning: Citation `battigalli2002sba' on page 2 undefined on input line 161. LaTeX Warning: Reference` definition6.1' on page 2 undefined on input line 200.

He got these errors when compiling under "Latex." I had suggested that he compile under "pdfLatex" but he doesn't have that option and instead has an option called "pdflatexmk." (I googled to understand the difference and couldn't figure that out.)  He gets many more errors under pdflatexmk.

I'm completely baffled by what is happening.  It almost seems like texshop is not talking to latex (though the rest of the file is compiling). Is there perhaps a missing step in his setup? Other ideas?

Update with the full set of errors below:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex) restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (./rsba-01-31-22.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/appendix/appendix.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chngcntr/chngcntr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.
tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sgame/sgame.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/quoting/quoting.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./rsba-01-31-22.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty)) (./rsba-01-31-22.out) (./rsba-01-31-22.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd)
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `battigalli2002sba' on page 1 undefined on input line 133.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `brandenburger2008ag' on page 1 undefined on input line 133.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `ASHEIM200561' on page 1 undefined on input line 133.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `blume1989lexico' on page 1 undefined on input line 133.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `halpern2010lexicographic' on page 1 undefined on input line 133.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `hammond1994elementary' on page 1 undefined on input line 133.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Package natbib Warning: Citation `battigalli2002sba' on page 2 undefined on input line 161.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `brandenburger2008ag' on page 2 undefined on input line 183.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `brandenburger2008ag' on page 2 undefined on input line 195.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.1' on page 2 undefined on input line 200.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.2' on page 2 undefined on input line 200.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6' on page 2 undefined on input line 200.
[2]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fact3' on page 3 undefined on input line 238.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fact2' on page 3 undefined on input line 251.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma2' on page 3 undefined on input line 251.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fact3' on page 3 undefined on input line 251.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma3' on page 3 undefined on input line 259.
[3]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition1.1' on page 4 undefined on input line 272.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition1.2' on page 4 undefined on input line 272.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition1.3' on page 4 undefined on input line 272.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition1.3' on page 4 undefined on input line 275.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition1.3' on page 4 undefined on input line 278.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma2' on page 4 undefined on input line 280.
[4]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma2' on page 5 undefined on input line 331.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma5' on page 5 undefined on input line 331.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma2' on page 5 undefined on input line 331.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma3' on page 5 undefined on input line 340.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma6' on page 5 undefined on input line 340.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition1' on page 5 undefined on input line 345.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition1' on page 5 undefined on input line 345.
[5]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fact3' on page 6 undefined on input line 359.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma6' on page 6 undefined on input line 359.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.3' on page 6 undefined on input line 365.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition2' on page 6 undefined on input line 374.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition3' on page 6 undefined on input line 389.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma7' on page 6 undefined on input line 391.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition2' on page 6 undefined on input line 391.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma2' on page 6 undefined on input line 391.
[6]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition1.3' on page 7 undefined on input line 393.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma2' on page 7 undefined on input line 399.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition1.1' on page 7 undefined on input line 417.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition1.2' on page 7 undefined on input line 417.
[7]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma8' on page 8 undefined on input line 424.
[8]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.1' on page 9 undefined on input line 479.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.2' on page 9 undefined on input line 479.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.3' on page 9 undefined on input line 479.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition6' on page 9 undefined on input line 485.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition6' on page 9 undefined on input line 497.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.1' on page 9 undefined on input line 501.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.2' on page 9 undefined on input line 501.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.3' on page 9 undefined on input line 505.
[9]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition6' on page 10 undefined on input line 508.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma9' on page 10 undefined on input line 508.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.1' on page 10 undefined on input line 511.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `definition6.2' on page 10 undefined on input line 511.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition2' on page 10 undefined on input line 529.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma3' on page 10 undefined on input line 539.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition5' on page 10 undefined on input line 548.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition6' on page 10 undefined on input line 548.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition3' on page 10 undefined on input line 556.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `corollary3' on page 10 undefined on input line 556.
[10]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `proposition6' on page 11 undefined on input line 574.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `lemma10' on page 11 undefined on input line 574.
(./rsba-01-31-22.bbl)
Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
[11] (./rsba-01-31-22.aux)
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `rsba-01-31-22.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
 ){/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-ts1.enc
}</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbxti10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></
usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb></us
r/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/
local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/lo
cal/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></usr/loca
l/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/local/t
exlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb></usr/local/texl
ive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/local/texli
ve/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb></usr/local/texlive
/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/
2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0600.pfb></usr/local/texlive/20
22/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb>
Output written on rsba-01-31-22.pdf (11 pages, 241347 bytes).
SyncTeX written on rsba-01-31-22.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on rsba-01-31-22.log.
```

Comment: Ask your coauthor to search through the logs to look for errors that are actually errors, and not just "warnings". Then post the errors here. (I think the missing references is most likely accidental symptoms of an actual issue, but we cannot troubleshoot it if we don't know what the actual problem is.)

Comment: He needs to run ‘bibtex’ (also available in the Typeset menu) and then LaTeX again (twice). By default TeXShop doesn’t use an automatic tool chain.

Comment: Thanks both: I do have the full set of errors (hadn't want to inundate you) but before I post them I'm going to double check that these are the errors after running bibtex plus latex twice.  More soon...

Comment: I read your question a little too fast. The LaTeX option in TeXShop runs the LaTeX engine, set in the preferences (usually `pdflatex` by defaultI). If he gets errors using `pdflatexmk` (which is an automated tool chain) on a document that you can compile, this seems quite strange. Does he have a copy of the `.bib` file containing the references as well as the source `.tex` file you are working on?

Comment: Yes, he has a copy of the .bib file. It is in a shared dropbox folder with me---same exact location---and i have no trouble compiling the file.  If it were only \citet that were not compiling, I would assume that its a problem of the .bib file.  But what's weird is that also ordinary references (i.e., \label{theorem1} followed by \ref{theorem1}) are also not compiling for him... I've made him to all of the above and still problems... about to update the question to include the full set of errors

Comment: I included the errors that he got after one round of bibtex followed by two rounds of latex. but he got errors also when compiling under pdflatexmk. I think analogous errors.  If its more helpful to see those, let me know.

Comment: I think this may be a Dropbox issue. Have him select the folder containing your files within the finder and right/control click and choose "Make Available Offline" from the set of Dropbox menu items that appear. Then try compiling again using `pdflatexmk`.  It might help to remove all the aux files first.

Comment: Ask him to check the dropbox folder for "sync conflict" files. (This would be files that have file name ending in something like `(<so-and-so>'s conflicted copy <date>)`.) My guess is that at some point Dropbox caught a sync conflict (possibly because the two of you are editing at the same time) and so it then prevents him from writing new `.aux` files (keeping each conflicted copy with the appended name). This results in the updated `.aux` files not being readable (as it has the wrong file name).

Comment: Ideally the solution would be to allow Dropbox to not sync any files generated by TeX (such as `aux`, `bbl`, `out`, `ind` and so on), but that is not supported by DropBox. You can work around this by having TeXShop configured to store the output files in a different subfolder (which you choose not to sync).

Comment: Alan's suggestion seemed to work with compiling via Latex. It does seem to be a dropbox issue and not a texshop issue--thanks!